# Custom RegEx for Username/Email Address Java

Tags: java, regex

Somehow I find it really hard to create a RegEx on my own and I am sure one of you does know how to work with them. My question: I want users, who register, to only be able to enter an email address of this format: `?.????@example.com`.

To clear up, my RegEx should look for if there is only one character in the first position, followed by a dot, an infinite number of characters, an at-symbol, followed by "example.com".

Is it even possible to allow RegEx to look for full strings (`example.com` in this case) and if so, what would that RegEx look like? (I'd like an full example).

By characters I mean alphanumeric characters (`^[a-zA-z]$`)

Comment: you say alphanumeric but example only contains alphabet

Comment: Parsing emails with regex isn't simple at all, I would recommend to read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) article, it explains the trade-offs in using one regex over another and what are some standards to use (even with standards, there are still some trade-offs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+@example\.com$
```

Demo and Explanation : https://regex101.com/r/BPFHvl/4

Comment: This would validate: _._@example.com

Comment: Amerongen says character, not that only alphanumeric

Comment: If possible, I did indeed meant alphanumeric characters, I will edit my question. Also, as shown in your example, `atest.sss@example.com` would validate as well.

Comment: @JvanAmerongen Answer updated

Comment: I tried this RegEx, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's a fixed one: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+@example\.com$`.

Comment: I forget to remove \